# How old is Finn?

Tags: adventure-time, age

How old is Finn in *Adventure Time*? Because it never says, yet he always looks the same from time to time when surely they can't have trouble every day.

Comment: Clicked on title without reading tag.  Assumed this was a question about Star Wars.  Didn't read actual question, and skipped straight to reading the answer.  Became very confused.

Comment: [About 23](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Finn) ... oops, wrong Finn.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## 17 years old, at time of posting this answer

In the Season 6 finale "The Comet", Finn states that he is 16:

> **FINN:** Besides, it was like 40 years ago. **I'm 16!** I don't have a star to revolve around to track time.

Since time in *Adventure Time* elapses at the same rate as in the real world, and since we are currently near the end of Season 7, this would make Finn **17 years old**.

Comment: Are we certain that time elapses at the same rate? That certainly isn't the case for all TV shows. Not that I'm disputing anything, just curious.

Comment: @DangerZone : Part of the premise of *Adventure Time* is that time elapses at a "normal" rate.  It's closer to a documentary than to a usual cartoon.

Comment: @DangerZone : Also, a few seasons earlier, in the episode "Mystery Train", Finn states that he is 13, which enforces the passage of time.