# How old is Rey?

Tags: marvel, age, sigil-comics

<sub>Question inspired by [AllieB's question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn).</sub>

How old is Rey in the Sigil comics? Is her age ever stated?

Comment: since you tagged it Marvel Comics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28comics%29 tells us she is 16 years in the Marvel relaunch, sadly unsourced, so just a comment, not an answer...

Comment: @BMWurm you can post it as an unsourced answer if you write the whole thing in block caps. No one will argue with block caps. 

Comment: [About 19](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rey) ... oops, wrong Rey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 16

According to the **[official Marvel web site](http://marvel.com/news/comics/14857/marvel_announces_a_new_imprint)**, Rey is 16 years old:

> SIGIL stars Samantha Rey, a **16-year-old girl from South Carolina** who gets swept up in a war beyond her understanding and may possess the power to turn the tide in the form of a mysterious symbol on her chest even she doesn't understand.

For the record, there is no evidence that she has aged since the comic was released in 2011 (that is, there is no evidence that time is elapsing in the comic at the same rate as in the real world).

Comment: Any information on how old she was in the original CrossGen comics? Can it be assumed to be the same?

Comment: @Ibid : Unless I'm mistaken, Rey wasn't a girl in the original CrossGen series.  The main character was Samandahl Rey, a soldier (a male, likely more than 20 years old) fighting for the Planetary Union.  Since you tagged the question Marvel and you wrote "her age", I focused the answer on Samantha Rey...