# How old is Luke?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, luke-cage

I don't think remember it being made clear as to what his age was. How old was Luke Cage in Marvel's Jessica Jones? Is he older than Jessica?

<sub>Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn).</sub>

Comment: You know, there's another very famous Luke. Perhaps your title would benefit from increased specificity.

Comment: @fredsbend - it's a gag. We had a [Finn question before](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn?lq=1). And I think a Rey question too. Took all my willpower not to dupehammer :)

Comment: The tags gave it away :)

Comment: @fredsbend - I guess you haven't see the similar questions about Rey and Finn?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115010/how-old-is-rey?lq=1

Comment: We never found out who his dad is either.

Comment: As old as his tongue and a little older than his teeth.

Comment: This is not the Luke you're looking for. You can go about your business.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## We don't know

Neither Marvel nor Netflix has published the age of Luke Cage as he appears in the television series *Marvel's Jessica Jones*.  Also, his age does not come up in any dialogue in the show.

I suspect, however, that Cage is intended to be slightly older than Jones, given that the actor who plays Cage, [Mike Colter](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Colter), is **39 years old** (at time of posting), while [Krysten Ritter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krysten_Ritter) is **34**. But as we know, ages of actors and their characters need not correspond.

Comment: Now that he has his own show, is there any more information. (Please avoid spoilers.)

Comment: @ibid : I'm keeping an eye on this and will update the answer if a reference is made. :-)

Comment: He now has a second season. Again, please try avoiding spoilers if you update.

Comment: @ibid : I’m watching for any relevant info. :-)