# How old is Tarkin?

Tags: age, demons, charmed

Although he doesn't appear so much, Tarkin was a significant antagonist before he died. He was a member of Brotherhood of the Thorn.
Is his age ever specified?

### How old is Tarkin in the TV series *Charmed*?

<sub>Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn).</sub>

Comment: THWACK. Sheesh.

Comment: We're trying to create a meme here, I presume?

Comment: @ibid : Gave this one another go, and still can't find anything more about this character.

Comment: @Praxis [This one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115886/how-old-were-the-rebels-wedge-and-biggs) still has *no* answer.

Comment: @ibid : Ah, I didn't even see that one --- thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We don't know

In his few appearances in the show, Tarkin's age is never specified.  I've scoured [episode scripts](http://www.charmedscripts.tv) and looked at interviews and other notes.

I'm happy if someone proves me wrong, but as far as my research is concerned, his age is never stated.