# How old is Chopper?

Tags: age, dredd, 2000ad

Chopper is a renegade, a fighter, and even a graffiti artist. He has had some run-ins with the authorities and with other droids. He even had a small cameo in one of the films. Do we know how old he is?

### When was Chopper (aka Marlon Shakespeare) from Judge Dredd born?

Comment: Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114983/how-old-is-finn).

Comment: At what point? He's a teenager in Unamerican Grafitti, a young adult in The Midnight Surfer. Oz happens three years after that.

Comment: I was just going to say, we see him at various points in his lifetime, ranging from his young teens through to his late twenties

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopper_(Judge_Dredd)

Comment: Perhaps changing the wording of the question from "how is he" to when "when was he born" would allow for a more definitive answer.

Comment: @Blackwood - Done. Not changing the title though as that would kinda ruin the whole question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is at least 49 years old if he is still alive in Judge Dredd.
Here is my calculation
2000Ad started in 1977 and it was the year 2099 in Judge Dredd. For each real year a year passed in Judge Dredd.
He first appeared in Prog 206 which was in 1981 = Judge Dredd year 2103 and he is described as a teenager so he is at least 13 years old. 
So 2017 -1981 is 36 year + 13 is 49

Comment: Interesting, but does an actual year pass each real year?